# Displaying an Image in the iPython qtconsole

Tags: python, ipython

I'm trying to display an image in the ipython qtconsole via:

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename='sky1024px.jpg')
```

But I get the following output

```
Out[6]: <IPython.core.display.Image object>
```

I installed python via Anaconda which has the needed library to display images.  I tried searching stackoverflow and couldn't find any answers yet.

The version of python i'm running is:

```
  IPython QtConsole 3.2.0
  Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, May 28 2015, 17:04:42)
```

The reason I want to get this working is I'm messing around with the google deepdream project which looks pretty fun and crazy.  See: https://github.com/google/deepdream/blob/master/dream.ipynb

Sorry if this is simple question never used python and i'm been banging my head on this for a few hours!

Thanks!

Comment: Mmm, nothing on this? I'm having the same isuue.

Comment: @Gerb,  I have the same issue.. did you figure it out ??

Comment: QtConsole still cannot display IPython Image objects (I tried `embed=True` to no avail)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work although I must admit I don't use IPython that much.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('/home/students/sky1024px.jpg')
im.show()
```

Comment: That indeed does work, which is what i'm doing in the meantime.  I just thought it would be nice to have the image display inline to the console. At least I've seen examples where people had this working.

Answer (score 1):

I found after I'd used `display` once `Image`s were rendered:

```
from IPython.core.display import Image, display
display(Image('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2a/Svm_max_sep_hyperplane_with_margin.png'))
```